# Force UTC time in Snowflake JOIN condition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, utc, timezone-offset

I have a setup where we have

1. A landing table with a column of type TIMESTAMP_LTZ (consumption_date). Includes the timezone of +02:00
2. A view (landing_view) that reads from the landing table
3. A view (raw_data) that reads from a table that has a field of type TIMESTAMP_NTZ (SOURCE_TIMESTAMP), but the value itself is in UTC time.

I have to join the data from landing_view to the data from raw_data using the consumption_date and SOURCE_TIMESTAMP.

```
SELECT l.ID, l.consumption_date, l.RUN_TIME, r.DISPLAY_NAME, r.source_timestamp, r.value_as_double
FROM "raw_data" r
JOIN "landing_view" l
ON r.SOURCE_TIMESTAMP >= DATEADD(second,120, convert_timezone('UTC',l.consumption_date))
  and r.SOURCE_TIMESTAMP < DATEADD(second,1000, convert_timezone('UTC',l.consumption_date))
```

My problem is that the convert_timezone command does not seem to affect the join clause at all, insted the join is made using the local time included in the LTZ type (+02:00).

If I use the convert_timezone is a select, if works just fine, but for the JOIN it does not.

Is there a way I can tell snowflake to use UTC in the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on what your TIMEZONE setting is. See example below.

If TIMEZONE is UTC:

```
alter session set TIMEZONE = 'UTC';
select 
    -- 2AM UTC
    '2021-01-02 02:00:00'::timestamp_ntz as SOURCE_TIMESTAMP,
    -- 1AM UTC / 12PM Australia/Melbourne time / 1 hour before SOURCE_TIMESTAMP
    '2021-01-02 12:00:00 +1100'::timestamp_ltz as CONSUMPTION_DATE,
    -- so add one hour to CONSUMPTION_DATE should equal to SOURCE_TIMESTAMP
    SOURCE_TIMESTAMP = DATEADD(hour, 1, convert_timezone('UTC', CONSUMPTION_DATE)) as is_equal
;

+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+
| SOURCE_TIMESTAMP              | CONSUMPTION_DATE              | IS_EQUAL |
|-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------|
| 2021-01-02 02:00:00.000000000 | 2021-01-02 01:00:00.000 +0000 | True     |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+
```

However, if you change your TIMEZONE setting to another timezone, the result will be different:

```
alter session set TIMEZONE = 'Australia/Melbourne';
select 
    -- 2AM UTC
    '2021-01-02 02:00:00'::timestamp_ntz as SOURCE_TIMESTAMP,
    -- 1AM UTC / 12PM Australia/Melbourne time / 1 hour before SOURCE_TIMESTAMP
    '2021-01-02 12:00:00 +1100'::timestamp_ltz as CONSUMPTION_DATE,
    -- so add one hour to CONSUMPTION_DATE should equal to SOURCE_TIMESTAMP
    SOURCE_TIMESTAMP = DATEADD(hour, 1, convert_timezone('UTC', CONSUMPTION_DATE)) as is_equal
;

+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+
| SOURCE_TIMESTAMP              | CONSUMPTION_DATE              | IS_EQUAL |
|-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------|
| 2021-01-02 02:00:00.000000000 | 2021-01-02 12:00:00.000 +1100 | False    |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+
```

Since you SOURCE_TIMESTAMP stores UTC value, you should change your TIMEZONE setting to match it.

By the way, having CONVERT_TIMEZONE in the DATEADD is redundant, as it only adds extra operation, but not having any effects. See below example:

```
select 
    -- 1AM UTC / 9AM Australia/Perth time / 1 hour before SOURCE_TIMESTAMP
    '2021-01-02 09:00:00 +0800'::timestamp_ltz as CONSUMPTION_DATE,
    DATEADD(hour, 1, CONSUMPTION_DATE) as no_convert_tz,
    DATEADD(hour, 1, convert_timezone('UTC', CONSUMPTION_DATE)) as convert_tz,
    no_convert_tz = convert_tz
;

+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+
| CONSUMPTION_DATE              | NO_CONVERT_TZ                 | CONVERT_TZ                    | NO_CONVERT_TZ = CONVERT_TZ |
|-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------|
| 2021-01-02 12:00:00.000 +1100 | 2021-01-02 13:00:00.000 +1100 | 2021-01-02 02:00:00.000 +0000 | True                       |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

You can see that the last column returns True.

Comment: Thank you Eric, your excellent explanation helped me to finally understand what snowflake does with datetimes. The end result was that I went to the origin of the data, converted it to UTC on the application level and changed snowflake timestamp type to NTZ. It was more in line with existing applications and no need to convert anything.